# AWS SDK echo output during multipart upload?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using the current version of the Amazon Web Services PHP SDK. I am attempting to upload a file to S3 using the multipart uploader. It's working like a charm!

Almost.

**Here's the most relevant portion of code.**

```
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
    ->setClient($s3)
    ->setSource($file_to_upload)
    ->setBucket($bucket)
    ->setKey($key)
    ->setMinPartSize(25 * 1024 * 1024)
    ->setOption('ACL', 'public-read')
    ->setConcurrency(3)
    ->build();

$uploader->upload();
```

Anyway. It works great. However, the RackSpace server I am using is kinda retarded, and it kills a script that is running too long without creating any output. This tends to be a problem when uploading very large files. Flushing data solves this issue, but... I can't for the life of me figure out how to output data mid-upload!

AWS has to support this, right? If so, what would be the simplest way of achieving this effect?

Answer (score 1):

The uploader emits several events that you can hook into. It's really not documented, so you may want to take a look at the code for [`Aws\Common\Model\MultipartUpload\AbstractTransfer`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Model/MultipartUpload/AbstractTransfer.php).

There are [6 events](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Model/MultipartUpload/AbstractTransfer.php#L33-L38) that you can use:

- `multipart_upload.before_upload`
- `multipart_upload.after_upload`
- `multipart_upload.before_part_upload`
- `multipart_upload.after_part_upload`
- `multipart_upload.after_abort`
- `multipart_upload.after_complete`

To register a listener for the event, you can do something similar to following before `$uploader->upload()`. In this listener, you can do whatever you want.

```
$uploader->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
    'multipart_upload.after_part_upload', 
    function($event) {
        // Do whatever you want
        echo $event['state']->count() . " parts uploaded.\n";
    }
);
```

There are a few things passed into the `$event` object available to the listener. [Look in the code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Model/MultipartUpload/AbstractTransfer.php#L223-L230) to see what data you'll receive.